# Keep current page rendered until the next page is loaded

Tags: android, webview

I have a simple app that is based on WebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com").

When a user clicks on a URL, the default behavior is to immediately show a blank page, wait until the page is loaded, and then show this page.

I managed to show a splash screen in lieu of the blank page. However, is it possible to keep the current page rendered instead, and render the next page only when it is fully loaded?

Comment: As a sidenote, you may want to consider adding a loading dialog (spinner) if you ever get this to work. Given that the default behavior in Android is to show a blank page, I would think that the link/button either didn't work, or the app was slow if it still hung on the previous page. Just food for thought.

Comment: For now I have a progress bar in addition to the splash screen, which is not very useful.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a "real" way to do this, but I just ran a test app with two `WebView`s whose visibilities are toggled when the page load is finished. It works rather nicely. I can post code, if you like.

Comment: I can accept this as an answer if no better alternative is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, I feel, a hacky solution. I offer it as a temporary fix until someone posts the "real" way to do this.

`MainActivity` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    WebView webView1, webView2;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_url);
        webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_1);
        webView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_2);

        webView1.setWebViewClient(client);
        webView2.setWebViewClient(client);

        webView1.loadUrl(editText.getText().toString());
    }

    private WebViewClient client = new WebViewClient()
    {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url)
        {
            if (webView == webView1)
                webView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else
                webView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "WebView " + (webView == webView1 ? "One" : "Two") + " is showing", 0).show();
        }
    };

    private void loadUrl(String url)
    {
        if (webView1.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            webView1.loadUrl(url);
        else
            webView2.loadUrl(url);
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        loadUrl(editText.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

`main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.webkit.WebView android:id="@+id/webView_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.webkit.WebView android:id="@+id/webView_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_url"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="http://www.example.com" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/button_load"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Load" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Accepted this answer as the only available solution.